# running a Rails app on a fresh installation of Nginx/Passenger causes error "no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04. I've installed Nginx and Passenger on it by following [these](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu) and [these instructions](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app), and as per the instructions, I've added to the `http` block of file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` the following lines:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

and the following block (where I've replaced the actual domain name by `www.example.com`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /srv/rails/myapp/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

The Rails application lives in directory `/srv/rails/myapp/`, which is also a Git project directory.  The directory and all its contents are owned by user `rails`.  I've made the directory world-writeable, and, as user `rails`, run the following commands in it:

```
git pull
gem install bundler
bundle install
rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

After this, running the application in development mode succeeds: when I command `rails s`, and open http://www.example.com:3000, the application works fine.

**However,** after doing the all the above, and commanding `sudo service nginx restart`, opening http://www.example.com yields a **Passenger error screen, which says:**

```
no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158
```

There's lots of debug output below that, and I'm not sure which of it is useful, but here's an excerpt:

```
Application root

    /srv/rails/myapp

Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)

    production

Ruby interpreter command

    /usr/bin/ruby

User and groups

    uid=1001(rails) gid=1002(rails) groups=1002(rails)

Environment variables

    SHELL = /bin/bash
    PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXX2fPMPM
    USER = rails
    PWD = /srv/rails/myapp
    SHLVL = 0
    HOME = /home/rails
    LOGNAME = rails
    SERVER_SOFTWARE = nginx/1.4.6
    IN_PASSENGER = 1
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
    NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
    RAILS_ENV = production
    RACK_ENV = production
    WSGI_ENV = production
    NODE_ENV = production
    PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
    SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
    SCGI = 1
    DOCUMENT_ROOT = /srv/rails/myapp/public
    QUERY_STRING =
    SERVER_NAME = www.example.com
    REMOTE_PORT = 49316
    REMOTE_ADDR = [redacted]
    SERVER_PORT = 80
    REQUEST_METHOD = GET
    SERVER_ADDR = [redacted]
    REQUEST_URI = /

...

General Ruby interpreter information

    RUBY_VERSION = 1.8.7
    RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
    RUBY_ENGINE = nil
    RubyGems version = 1.8.15
```

The application uses Ruby v2.0.0p353 while Passenger seems to use v1.8.7; I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this problem. (The Ruby used by the app lives in `/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/`.)

I've searched for other problems where Passengers outputs this error, but nothing I've tried so far fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various things, I gave up on having nginx installed from Debian packages.  I removed it, and also removed my rubies and RVM, then reinstalled everything, following [these directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu).  The article advises how to install nginx using the `passenger-install-nginx-module` command that comes with the passenger gem.  It checks all dependencies, and if it can proceed, downloads and compiles nginx.  By default, it's installed in `/opt/nginx/`.

This did not work immediately.  I also had to create an nginx startup script; instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/257109/38043).  Furthermore, I had to edit the `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file to add a reference to my application, and also had to comment out the `location /` block.  After all this, and commanding `sudo service nginx restart`, the site is up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if this will help, but try, in your projects folder:

```
which ruby # for example /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
```

And this will output which ruby your bundle is using. Put that value, replacing this:

```
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
```

to this

```
passenger_ruby /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
```

end

**edit:**

this Linux command:

```
echo $MY_RUBY_HOME/bin/ruby
```

might be the easiest and most correct way to find your ruby binary.

Comment: Nope, that will only result in the following Passenger errors shown in the browser: `could not find a temporary directory (ArgumentError) /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:34:in \`tmpdir'`, plus stacktrace. Surely Passenger should be able to use its own Ruby version, the application its own? (Said he, hopefully.)

Comment: You should use YOUR directory, not mine

Comment: The directory name you gave is exactly the same directory I'm using, as I'm using Ruby v2.0.0-p353, and am deploying the app as user `rails`.

Comment: I appreciate your trying to help, but I'm simply reporting the results. (And I'm not the one who gave your answer a downvote.)

Comment: Sorry then. I thought it was, and it bothered cause there was no other answer or anyone else even risking to help. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: Thanks. The question has only been up a few hours, so maybe someone will supply an answer. I'll keep looking for a solution, and if I find one, I'll report it as an answer.